# Datetime axis label in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have this plot that I am getting the data form a MSSQL table in JSON format but the datetime axis labels shows only one point. The datetime format in the JSON is epoc format [1325397600000,1325484000000,1325570400000,1325656800000,1325743200000,1325829600000].

What possibly is the problem?

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 60
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Pressure and Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
     type: 'datetime',



            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature '
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: []

        }

        $.getJSON("data3.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
    options.series[1] = json[2];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });
    });
```

Comment: can you share a js fiddle with sample data that will reproduce the same issue you have got

Answer (score 0):

In these lines:

```
options.series[0] = json[1];
options.series[1] = json[2];
```

You try to add two series, but based on your JSON it meanas that you try to reference to one point for series, in other words your construction means:

```
 options.series[0] = 1325397600000;
 options.series[1] = 1325484000000;
```

I advice to familiar with correct series structure (data array included).

http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing